# Code to get the line where a word is placed on a txt file

Tags: vba

I'm unable to write a code that looks for a word in a txt file and return the line where the word is placed.

The word is usually at the 31th line (placed at the start of the string) but sometimes is placed below. I tried to make a loop that stopped at the 32th line and it worked, but when the string is placed on a different number line the code doesn't work.

That's because I thought on looking for the word and then getting the line.

I've tried some copy-paste codes from many places but I couldn't managed to make them work.

Here is a sample of the *.txt file:

```
%%%
  VERSION:1
  LANGUAGE:ENGLISH
%%%

MODULE RP02


PROC P02()
ConfL\Off;
ConfJ\Off;
vfeed.v_tcp := 20;
vfeed.v_ori := 300;
vrapid.v_tcp := 500;
vrapid.v_ori := 300;
vfeed.v_leax := 500;
vfeed.v_reax := 20;
vrapid.v_leax := 1000;
vrapid.v_reax := 20;
CurrZone.pzone_tcp :=1;
CurrZone.pzone_ori :=2;
CurrZone.pzone_eax := 100;
CurrZone.zone_leax := 30;
CurrZone.zone_reax := 30;
AccSet 10,50;

CurrWObj := caja1;
CurrWObj.oframe.trans := [0,0,0];
CurrWObj.oframe.rot := [1,0,0,0];
! Item ID 2.1: NCL Code - Carga herramienta_02_D63_L520_H12_CAR=1

LoadTool 2,H12_PAT_1,1,1;
! Item ID 2.2: NCL Code - Posicionamiento ST180 R
MoveAbsJ [[96.98,-14.64,15.98,87.92,-32.69,-87.52],[2040,0,0,0,0,0]],vrapid,CurrZone,CurrTool;
MoveAbsJ [[96.98,-14.64,15.98,87.92,-32.69,-87.52],[2540,0,0,0,0,0]],vrapid,CurrZone,CurrTool;
!---------------------------------------------
```

And this is the code that worked previously:

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim f As File
Dim fsoStream As TextStream
Dim strLine As String
Dim j As Integer

Set f = fso.GetFile("C:\fileToRead.txt")
Set fsoStream = f.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)

j = 1

Do Until j > 32


strLine = fsoStream.ReadLine
Debug.Print strLine

j = j + 1

Loop
```

But when the string where "LoadTool" is placed changes the line number this doesn't work...

I tried to modify copy/pastes I found on the web in order to achieve a FIND function or something similar and get the line number but I got stucked...

Comment: I tried to copy paste at least the content of the *.txt file to be clearer but I get an error when I post it because I'm doing something wrong about the format but I don't know what...

Comment: That should work: Paste your code/data in the editor, mark it and format it as code block (Ctrl + K). Make sure you do not post the entire file content but a representative sample of your data. Make sure to paste your VBA code that did not work and mention in which lines you got errors or where exactly you got stuck. • Without that information we are not able to tell what you did wrong and we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you stop at line 32. Just run the loop `Until fsoStream.AtEndOfStream` and check each line for your `SearchWord`. If found then exit the loop.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Example()
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    
    Dim f As Object
    Set f = fso.GetFile("C:\fileToRead.txt")
    
    Dim fsoStream As TextStream
    Set fsoStream = f.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)
    
    Dim SearchWord As String
    SearchWord = "LoadTool"

    Dim WasFound As Boolean
    WasFound = False  'initialization needed for loops!        

    Dim strLine As String
    Do Until fsoStream.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = fsoStream.ReadLine
        DoEvents 'do not freeze Excel give
        
        If Left$(strLine, Len(SearchWord)) = SearchWord Then
            'MsgBox "'" & SearchWord & "' was found."
            WasFound = True
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    
    If WasFound Then
        'strLine now contains
        'LoadTool 2,H12_PAT_1,1,1;
        
        'put your code to handle that file here
    Else
        'search word was not found
        
        'put your code to handle what should happen if search word was not found
        'or omit the entire Else part to just skip that file.
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked fine!

Comment: @Victor see my edit for how to skip files that do not have the keyword.

Comment: sorry for coming back to this... But is there a way to read only the (for example) 20 first lines of the txt file and not continuing to the EndOfStream? Because I work with txt files with over 50k lines, it takes a long time to calculate and the key word to find in this case is placed between the first and the 20th line.

Comment: Well, I found the solution. I only had to change the fsoStream.AtEndOfStream for fsoStream.Line > 20 and it's done.